# Prevent value duplication in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am trying to add 'Car' object to the database. It has several values from various and I don't want any of them to be duplicated. Example :

I have a 'CarType' table. There are four fields in it:

- Sedan
- Jeep
- Hatchback
- Coupe

When adding a new car, User chooses one of those fields(Ex. Sedan) and I don't want 'CarType' table to have another 'Sedan' field in it.

[Application Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8RF.png)

I tried to prevent duplication with this solution:

```
        Manufacturer checkManufacturer;
        Model checkModel;
        Levy checkLevy;
        DealType checkDealType;
        FuelType checkFuelType;
        Transmission checkTransmission;
        CarType checkCarType;
        Wheel checkWheel;

        using (var _ctx = new MyAutoGuramEntities2())
        {
            checkManufacturer = _ctx.Manufacturers.Where(c => c.Title.Equals(manufacturerInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkModel = _ctx.Models.Where(c => c.Title.Equals(modelInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkLevy = _ctx.Levies.Where(c => c.LevyValue.Equals(levyInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkDealType = _ctx.DealTypes.Where(c => c.TypeTitle.Equals(dealTypeInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkFuelType = _ctx.FuelTypes.Where(c => c.FuelTypeTitle.Equals(fuelTypeInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkTransmission = _ctx.Transmissions.Where(c => c.TransmissionType.Equals(transmissionInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkCarType = _ctx.CarTypes.Where(c => c.CarTypeValue.Equals(carTypeInput)).FirstOrDefault();
            checkWheel = _ctx.Wheels.Where(c => c.Side.Equals(wheelInput)).FirstOrDefault();
        }



        using (var _context = new MyAutoGuramEntities2())
        {
            //MANUFACTURER
            var manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
            if(checkManufacturer != null)
            {
                if (manufacturerInput != checkManufacturer.Title)
                {
                    manufacturer = new Manufacturer
                    {
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Title = manufacturerInput
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    manufacturer = new Manufacturer
                    {
                        ID = checkManufacturer.ID,
                        Title = checkManufacturer.Title
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                manufacturer = new Manufacturer
                {
                    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Title = manufacturerInput
                };
            }


            //MODEL
            var model = new Model();
            if (checkModel != null)
            {
                if (modelInput != checkModel.Title)
                {
                    model = new Model()
                    {
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Title = modelInput,
                        ManufacturerID = manufacturer.ID
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    model = new Model()
                    {
                        ID = checkModel.ID,
                        Title = checkModel.Title,
                        ManufacturerID = checkModel.ManufacturerID
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                model = new Model()
                {
                    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Title = modelInput,
                    ManufacturerID = manufacturer.ID
                };
            }


            //CarType
            var carType = new CarType();

            if (checkCarType != null)
            {
                if (carTypeInput != checkCarType.CarTypeValue)
                {
                    carType = new CarType()
                    {
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        CarTypeValue = carTypeInput
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    carType = new CarType()
                    {
                        ID = checkCarType.ID,
                        CarTypeValue = checkCarType.CarTypeValue
                    };
                }

            }
            else
            {
                carType = new CarType()
                {
                    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    CarTypeValue = carTypeInput
                };
            }
```

And so on on every property.. 
In the end I add everything to the DB this way :

```
  _context.Manufacturers.Add(manufacturer);
            _context.Models.Add(model);
            _context.CarTypes.Add(carType);
            _context.FuelTypes.Add(fuelType);
            _context.Levies.Add(levy);
            _context.DealTypes.Add(dealType);
            _context.Wheels.Add(wheel);
            _context.Transmissions.Add(transmission);
```

This code caused PrimaryKey error. Specifically :

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CarType'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CarType'. The duplicate key value
>   is (bb08d23a-f583-4b24-a335-282cd90e9299). The statement has been
>   terminated.

I understand the cause of the problem. CarType's ID can not be duplicated, but how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. I imagine that "Sedan","Jeep" are records(rows), not fields... and each one has an Id, right ?

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Will edit it. Just fixed the problem. If checkCarType variable is not null then 'cartype = checkCarType' instead of creating new CarType object.

Comment: but now is it solved?

Comment: Yes. If the object already existed I made new object and it was obvious that the ID would be duplicated and the exception would pop out.